# Make a list understand which item is selected C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm stuck.

I have 2 different listviews, the listview1 contains name, and the listview2 are showing the episodes to the name i selected in listview1.

The problem is that i want to have a description in a label of the specific episode i select in the listview2.

Right now i have all episodes in order in the listview2, and just for testing i have made a listview3 who shows all the descriptions in a list.

i pick out the information from  and i use

To get the descriptions.
But the problem is that i dont know how to connect the right episode to the right description. Have someone done something similiar before?

Right now i just loop trough the list and make it appear inte the listview3, but its not correct.

To get the episodes from the url to the list i use

Comment: Lists have no selections. It's the *UI element* that has user-selected items. All controls that allow selection have a `SelectedItem` property or something similar.

Comment: *What* stack are you using? Winforms? WPF? Both provide data binding, selections and *multiple properties*. They use different mechanisms though. In both cases, you should create *one* list of `ID, Title, Detail` objects and bind the control to that.

Comment: Im using winforms (sorry)

Comment: But how am i suppose to create a list of ID, i dont understand how i can make rss information unique to every episode, and then tell the label to show the description for the specific episode i have selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate once through your items and update both lists.

```
      foreach (SyndicationItem episode in feed.Items)
      {

          var episodeName = episode.Title.Text;
          var episodeDesc = episode.Summary.Text;

          podcastEpisodes.Add(episodeName);
          episodeDescription.Add(episodeDesc);
      }
```

To [set the selected item in a listview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-select-an-item-in-the-windows-forms-listview-control), you can set its selected/focus state.

Comment: This was very good. But how am i supposed to set the episodeDesc to the label (where i want the description to show up). I'm new to this..

Comment: Should be something like myLabel.Text = x. A bit hard to tell without the code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you simply do this:

```
lvEpisode.Where(x=> x.Name == NameListView.SelectedItem).Select(x=>x.Name).FirstOrDefault();
```

This assumes you have a class of item containing Name.

(Typing through mobile, this maynot compile):

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to convert your episode description from a list to a dictionary? The key would be the episode and the value would be the description. When user selects the episode then you just need to index the dictionary to get the description?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Bi7ic5Er, Here i have insert both episode and description in the dictionary. But now i want to select a episode in the listview and then loop through the dictionary and find the right key, and then insert the description to the label, but i dont know how to fix this ..

Comment: so on the episode list view there must be an event fired (list_changed) saying the value has changed. In this event do the following, extract the value. Then index the dictionary to find the description. Finally set the label to the text.

Comment: Here is a code sample (not got visual studio so might contain syntax errors)
`private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(this.listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
    return;

  string episode = this.listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text;
  string description = dictionary[episode];
  this.label1.Text = description;
  
}`

Answer (score -1):

since you are getting a xml data, try parsing as a JSON and the information will likely structured. so the index you use for your episodes should also be used to index the description. so a JSON like

```
movies={name: "Walking Dead" ,
    category: "Horror",
    episode:"episode1",
    description:"walkers rise again"};
```

so you can now get movies["episode"]; and movies["description"] easily.

They are online parsers you can put in xml and convert to JSON and also packages for c# too i believe, but put the xml [HERE](https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-to-json-converter.html) and see how the structure changes.